# Peut-on remplacer une proposition de condition par un verbe au conditionnel ?

Tags: grammaire, oral, conditionnel, conditions

À l’oral (ou à l’écrit informel), je construis fréquemment des phrases comme « J’aurais su, je ne serais pas venu. » plutôt que « Si j’avais su, je ne serais pas venu. »

Tout naturellement, quand il m’arrive de sous entendre la conclusion, je préfère dire

> Il a plu durant tout mon séjour à la plage. J’aurais su…

que

> Il a plu durant tout mon séjour à la plage. Si j’avais su…

On me le reproche parfois. Ce sont souvent les personnes qui entendent un « Si j’aurais su, je ne serais pas venu. » que je ne me permettrais pas, mais la question de la validité de la construction est alors sur le tapis et je manque à chaque fois de références pour défendre ma position.

J’ai bien cherché à cautionner ou à infirmer l’usage à l’aide de mon Grevisse, mais je dois avouer mon incapacité à extraire efficacement la moindre information de l’ouvrage. Je me souviens avoir lu je ne sais où que la construction était correcte lorsque le verbe et le sujet étaient inversés (cf. [réponse de @psychoslave](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6829/82)).

Cette construction est correcte ? Relève-t-elle d’un belgicisme ou d’un autre localisme ?

Comment: Pourriez-vous expliciter votre usage du pronom **à** dans « ... et je manque **à** chaque fois de référence » ? Pourquoi pas « ... et je manque chaque fois de référence » ?

Comment: Ne serait-ce pas l’objet d’une nouvelle question ? [Sinon, voir chaque dans le TLFi, entrée C-2](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chaque).

Answer (score 9):

La règle est la suivante :

> Après « si » marquant une condition, le mode conditionnel est **interdit**.

Cette règle invalide l'exemple connu :

> Si j’aurais su, je ne serais pas venu.

Par contre, il est tout à fait possible d'utiliser le conditionnel sans *si*.
Notamment pour exprimer le regret comme dans l'exemple cité dans la question :

> Il a plu durant tout mon séjour à la plage. J’aurais su… [je ne serais pas resté]

La phrase sera incorrecte seulement si un *si* précède « J'aurais su ».

Personnellement, je préfère utiliser le *si* pour marquer clairement le conditionnel et j'aurai plus tendance à opter pour la version :

> Il a plu durant tout mon séjour à la plage. Si j’avais su… [je ne serais pas resté]

Pour répondre clairement à la question initiale, il n'est pas interdit de trouver deux conditionnels dans la même phrase, comme dans l'exemple suivant :

> Quand bien même je le saurais, je ne le dirais pas.

**Sources:**

- [Synapse-fr](http://www.synapse-fr.com/manuels/CONDITIO.htm)
- [Figaro conjugaison](http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/fremploiconditionnel.php)
- [Le français pour tous](http://www.lefrancaispourtous.com/conditionnel.htm)

Comment: J’avoue que le titre est mal choisi (j’ai envisagé le « quand bien même »), mais je n’ai pas mieux à proposer. La terme « double conditionnelle » est-il compréhensible ?

Comment: Par ailleurs, tu cautionnes mon usage, mais, sauf erreur de ma part, aucune de tes sources ne l’évoque. Cela me rassure de voir qu’il ne te choque pas, mais j’aimerais avoir des arguments plus solides à apporter.

Comment: Je n'ai effectivement pas mentionné de source qui cautionnes ton usage car c'est une déduction des règles : soit tu utilises un verbe au conditionnel, soit tu utilises _si_ (mais pas les 2 en même temps!). Tout cela est bien expliqué [ici](http://yannickpiault.blogspot.fr/2013/01/lecon-de-langue-francaise-n1-si-jaurais.html) (section "La solution...")

Comment: Hormi sur ton dernier lien (merci), je ne vois rien qui propose « utiliser un verbe au conditionnel » comme alternative à la construction avec une conjonction (enfin, je crois que c’est une conjonction).

Answer (score 6):

À propos de cette structure dans Grevisse (citations et références du *Bon Usage*, 12<sup>e</sup> édition)

§859, a 2<sup>o</sup> Indique que le conditionnel présent marque un fait conjectural ou imaginaire, dans le futur.  Le fait conjectural peut dépendre ou non de la réalisation d'une condition, celle-ci pouvant avoir des expressions diverses (et se trouve alors un renvoi au §1079, d).

Ce paragraphe traite des mécanismes autres que les propositions conjonctives pour former des propositions adverbiales.  Le cas qui nous intéresse est le point 3 ou des sous-phrases juxtaposées sans marqueurs grammaticaux peuvent être en fait reliées logiquement. Un des exemples est : *Le danger serait dix fois plus grand, je l'affronterais.* Outre l'équivalent « *Même si le danger était dix fois plus grand…* », Grevisse référence une autre construction avec le même sens « *Le danger serait dix fois plus grand que je l'affronterais.* »

Dans cette construction qualifiée de pseudo-proposition (§1067), on utilise *que* pour rendre visible un lien logique implicite, avec souvent pour effet *d'inverser la hiérarchie logique* : la sous-phrase devenue proposition par l'introduction du *que* est souvent la partie la plus importante du message.

Pour revenir à ton fragment :

> Il a plu durant tout mon séjour à la plage. J’aurais su…

Il me semble que tu fais une ellipse d'un pronom personnel ayant comme antécédent la phrase précédente. (Ce genre d'ellipse me semble courante dans le langage parlé, mais j'ai pas cherché si Grevisse en disait quelque chose.)

> Il a plu durant tout mon séjour à la plage. Je l’aurais su…

Ce pronom ajouté, quelle que soit la manière dont tu complètes la phrase (avec ou sans *que*), il me semble que cela correspond à la structure décrite.

Comment: La 14ᵉ édition, [§1121 e) 1ᵒ] ne donne que des exemples avec inversion sujet-verbe. Mais peut-être lis-je le mauvais paragraphe. Je regarde si j’en trouve plus dans les éditions que possèdent mes géniteurs lors de ma prochaine visite.

Answer (score 5):

Je pense que tu peux utiliser des formulations comme :

> Il a plu durant tout mon séjour à la plage. **L**’aurais-je su…

Dans l’usage que je constate, cette formulation ne choque pas.

La phrase suivante :

> Quand bien même je le saurais, je ne le dirais pas

Peut également être formulé :

> Le saurais-je, je n’en dirais rien.

Ce qui dans mon expérience sonne plus usuel.

Comment: C’est effectivement cet usage que j’avais constaté ailleurs (et non pas une quelconque histoire de négative). Ce qui me fait dire que mon usage n’est au pire que très relativement fautif. Je continue de chercher.

Comment: Usuel ?! Correct, plutôt.

Comment: C’est peut-être correct, mais n’ayant pas en tête les règles de grammaire pour le démontrer, je ne peux qu’avancer que c’est usuel.

Comment: "L’aurais-je su", "le saurais-je", ne sont pas des formulations usuelles. Elles appartiennent à un registre soutenu.

Comment: Par usuel, je n’exclus aucun registre : tel que je le conçois, un dictionnaire usuel n’exclue ni les mots du registre vulgaire, ni ceux du registre littéraire.

Answer (score 3):

La construction est correcte [si on en croit la Grammaire de Gabriel Wyler](http://www.gabrielwyler.com/page636.html#Leconditionneldanslapr%E9missesansconjonction) (que je ne connaissais pas il y a une heure).

Il y cite notamment (des dialogues dans les deux cas, cependant) :

> [Nous serions réduites à la dernière misère, ni moi ni ta fille nous ne te ferions un seul reproche.](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Histoire_de_la_grandeur_et_de_la_d%C3%A9cadence_de_C%C3%A9sar_Birotteau/Chapitre_I._C%C3%A9sar_%C3%A0_son_apog%C3%A9e)

Balzac, *in* **César Biroteau**

> [Françoise, vous seriez venue cinq minutes plus tôt, vous auriez vu passer Mme Imbert [...]](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Du_c%C3%B4t%C3%A9_de_chez_Swann/Partie_1#80)

Proust, *in* **Du côté de chez Swann**

Answer (score 0):

C'est correct et pas du tout familier. Vous l'utiliseriez, vous le sauriez. ;)

Comment: Pour reprendre la phrase: «il aurait plu...., j'aurais su...» et ça passe très bien. Je trouve même que c'est plus joli que la version avec «si...».

Comment: Personnellement, ça m'écorche les oreilles. M'enfin, les goûts et les couleurs...

Comment: Chacun ses goûts, oui. Tant que ça reste correct.