# What exactly does "que" mean in these constructions that mean "if", but lack "si"?

Tags: constructions, conditionnel, subordonnées

1. This syntax lacks *si* to signify "if". So where does the meaning of "(even) if" hail from?
2. [que](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#French) itself doesn't mean "if". But que stems from Latin [quod](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quod#Latin) or [quia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quia#Latin). Would *quod* or *quia* explain this syntax below?

> [image]

Glanville Price, *A Comprehensive French Grammar* (2007 6 ed) p 330.

[image]

Roger Hawkins, *French Grammar and Usage* (2015 4 ed), p 408.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6836/358) explains the use of *que* in this conditional construction.

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation you need is contained in your reference, there is no more profound principle underlying this grammar. You are dealing with *a construction*, an idiomatic turn, which in virtue of a conjuncture of given characteristics takes on a certain meaning; as your reference says, this conjuncture is "*[an] otherwise subordinate clause (the 'if'-clause) in a conditional sentence becomes the subordinate clause, introduced by* que, *with the conditional or past conditional in both clauses*".

- {[clause w. v. in cond p.]  + **que** (conj.) + [clause w. v. in cond. p.] }        ↔
                                                                         {[If clause w. v. in imperf. ind.] +  clause w. v. in p.cond.}

However, the point that there exists in this correspondence a match between types of clauses is  questionable, as purports § 1121 in LBU.  (bolded type except section title due to user LPH)

> **§ 1121**   **Pseudo-propositions.**
> **a)**
> Lorsque des sous-phrases sont coordonnées d'une manière implicite, il y a entre elles une liaison logique. La langue semble ne pas se satisfaire de l'absence d'un lien visible, et elle tend à le marquer au moyen de la conjonction *que*, ce qui a souvent pour effet d'inverser la hiérarchie logique : la sous-phrase devenue proposition par l'introduction du *que* est souvent la partie la plus importante du message.
>
> **La première sous-phrase équivaut à une propos. de temps** :
> ♦ *J'étais gamine,* QU'*elle achetait déjà des navets à mon père*. (ZOLA, Ventre de P., I)
> ♦ *Tout s'était envolé* QUE *les Français tiraient toujours*. (BARRÈS, Union sacrée, p. 216)
> ♦ *A peine avait-il son bonheur entre les mains* QU'*on voulait le lui reprendre*. (FLAUB., Éduc., 1,6)
> ♦ *Elle était à peine remise* QU'*elle retomba malade*. (Robert métbod., s. v. peine)
>
> **La première sous-phrase équivaut à une propos. de condition** :
> ♦ *Le diable entrerait dans la maison* QU'*on le laisserait faire*.(HUGO, Misér., 1,1,9)
> ♦  *Je serais ministre de l'Éducation nationale,* QUE *j'inscrirais au programme de l'agrégation d'histoire la sociologie, la psychologie, l'économie politique, etc.*.  (BRAUDEL, interviewé dans le Magazine littér., nov. 1984, p. 22)
> ♦ *Eût-il tort,* QU'*il se soumettrait sans effort*.  (BRUNOT, Hist, t. III, p. 57)
> ♦ *Partait-il seul pour Paris* QU'*elle s'empressait de prévenir Mme Marliani. (MAUROIS, Lélia, p. 321)
> ♦ *L'idée vous vient-elle de vous séparer de celui-ci* QU'*il vous fiche mauvaise conscience*. (PIVOT, dans Lire, sept. 1986)
>
> **Un *que* analogue s'introduit, dans la langue parlée familière après *à ce qu'il
> (ou qui) parait*** […] **De même après *je te (ou vous) crois***
> ♦ *« Regarde donc la comtesse de Mascaret comme elle est toujours belle.* » / [...]
> *Quand il l'eut regardée quelque temps, Bernard Grandin répondit avec un accent
> badin de conviction sincère : / « JE TE CROIS QU'*elle est belle* !»*
> C'est une formule servant à souligner l'approbation […] ; elle n'entre pas facilement dans les cadres syntaxiques.

"**§ 286** Remarque" adds the following point of view.

> Dans *Je te* CROIS *qu'elle est belle*, [la partie] *qu'elle est
> belle* est une pseudo-proposition, à laquelle il
> serait difficile de donner une fonction précise. Cf. § 1121, a.

Therefore, the idea of main and subordinate clauses would not have much relevance in this construction.

Incidentally, notice first that the examples in the first paragraph (first bold type title) show that a change in the moods and tenses in the same construction make complete abstraction of the notion of condition. Then, notice that the last example in the second paragraph (second bold type title) shows that the present conditional  and the past conditional are not the only tenses and moods that ensure the notion of condition; so does the present indicative.