# When a coordinated clause extends a hypothetical clause introduced by si, why's the second clause introduced by que, not si?

Tags: sens, constructions, conditionnel

1. [que](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#French), its Latin etymons  [quod](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quod#Latin) and [quia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quia#Latin), all never signified *si* or "if". Then why would que introduce the second clause?
2. How ungrammatical, unidiomatic or heathen is it to write *si* where my red arrows below are pointing, rather than *que/qu'*?

[image]
Roger Hawkins, *French Grammar and Usage* (2015 4 ed), p 272.

Comment: Some of the answers to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6827/358) partly answers yours.

Answer (score 3):

It can, but it is not mandatory. Both ***que*** and ***si*** can be used to coordinate conditional propositions and both are common and grammatical.

In the former case, ***que*** is just a generic conjunction used to avoid repeating ***si***. Not using any conjunction might even be a better style as long as both clauses share the same subject.

A. With the indicative (see note below) and *si ... et que ...*:

1. *S'il retéléphone demain et **qu**'il veut savoir où j'étais, dis-lui que j'étais chez ma mère.*
2. *Si Hélène hérite de la maison et **qu**'elle la vend, tante Zoé sera furieuse.*
3. *Si le temps change et **qu**'il se met à pleuvoir, on annulera la sortie*

B. Repeating *si* :

1. *S'il retéléphone demain et **s**'il veut savoir où j'étais, dis-lui que j'étais chez ma mère.*
2. *Si Hélène hérite de la maison et **si** elle la vend, tante Zoé sera furieuse.*
3. *Si le temps change et **s**'il se met à pleuvoir, on annulera la sortie*

C. Dropping the conjunction:

1. *S'il retéléphone demain et veut savoir où j'étais, dis-lui que j'étais chez ma mère.*
2. *Si Hélène hérite de la maison et la vend, tante Zoé sera furieuse.*

   Impossible here as the subjects are different (*le temps* vs the impersonal *il*):
3. *Si le temps change <s>et se met à pleuvoir</s>, on annulera la sortie*

Note that all three sentences of this grammar book are using a subjunctive that sounds outdated and that I had never heard or read before doing some research.

The *Grammaire de l'Académie*, 1842, states (bold mine):

> *Que* sert à éviter la répétition de beaucoup de
> conjonctions telles que *comme, quand, si, lorsque, puis-
> que, quoique, attendu que*, etc : *comme Dieu est bon et
> Qu'il est juste, il récompensera la vertu*, c'est-à-dire *et
> comme il est juste.* — ***S'il vient** et qu'il **veuille** me parler*, c'est-à-dire, *et s'il veut*, etc.

Grevisse in *Le Bon usage* states both the subjunctive and indicative are used.

> **1157 Mode après que remplaçant si.**
>   Après que remplaçant si (ou comme si) dans la coordination de propositions conditionnelles (§ 1078, h, 2°), on met, selon l'usage le plus soigné, le subjonctif
> [...]
> Cependant on trouve aussi l'indicatif:
> [...]

Quote from Léautaud, Proust, de Gaulle, Mauriac are present in the second list so indicative is clearly not a colloquial only mood.

Modern usage almost always use the indicative:

> D'ici un mois, le coronavirus peut partir et s'il **part** et que je **dois** lutter, je dois être prêt. [Challenges.fr](https://www.challenges.fr/sport/coronavirus-a-dakar-les-stars-de-la-lutte-senegalaise-s-entrainent-a-huis-clos_706249)

> S'il **part** et que Boateng **s'en va** aussi, la défense aura cet aspect. [fcbayern-fr.com](https://fcbayern-fr.com/forum/transferts/transferts-bayern/pages/83/)

> S’il **vient** chez moi et qu’il **dort** dans la baignoire, je fais couler de l’eau afin qu’on prenne un bain ensemble et qu’il me gratte le dos. [topito.com](https://www.topito.com/top-raison-ryan-reynolds-amour)

Comment: LPH uses the subjunctive in their examples, whereas you say the indicative is correct. Can someone resolve this?

Comment: @HarryAudus Answer updated to clarify/correct this point. LPH replies should always be taken with a pinch of salt as he looks to have very little practical experience with spoken French, if any.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

A conjunction can be either *repeated*, or *repeated by representing it through the use of  the marker « que »*, or also, *neither repeated nor represented*. This shown in in *§ 1078 B)** from LBU. The answer to why « que » can be used does not come as a hard and fast reasoning but rather as a common sense deduction that appears appealing enough;  the facts to be found in a parenthesis in *§ 1078 B)** from LBU provide the  support; . (bold type except title due to user LPH)

> **§ 1078 b) 2°**
> **Coordination de deux propositions complètes**
> **1°** *Si* de l'interrogation indirecte, comme comparatif et *que* se répètent nécessairement
> **2°**
> Les autres conjonctions peuvent, ou bien être répétées (surtout si les
> propositions sont senties comme nettement distinctes), ou bien être reprises par *que*, ou bien, plus rarement, n'être ni répétées ni reprises par *que*.
> •
> **La conjonction est répétée** :
> ♦ *Si j'étais toujours professeur et* SI *je siégeais dans un jury, les ignorances ne me surprendraient pas*.  (GAXOTTE, Les autres et moi, p. 141)
> ♦ *Nous ne pourrons plus nous voir sans rougir tous les deux,* SANS QUE *je me sente mourir de honte et* SANS QUE *tes yeux ne fassent baisser les miens*.  (MAUPASS., Pierre et Jean, VII)
> •
> **La conjonction est reprise par *que*** :
> ♦ *Comme le maître était absent et* QU'*ils se trouvaient nombreux, ils mangeaient et ils buvaient en pleine liberté*.  (FLAUB., SaL, I)
> ♦ *Lorsqu'il faisait noir*, QUE *les chiens de la ferme voisine commençaient à hurler et QUE le carreau de notre petite cuisine s'illuminait, je rentrais enfin.*  (ALAIN-FOURNIER, Gr. Meaulnes, I, 2)
> ♦ *Même quand la pluie faisait rage et* QUE *Françoise avait précipitamment rentré les précieux fauteuils d'osier*. (PROUST, Rech., 1.1, p. 11)
> ♦ *Comme si vous bandiez un arc et* QUE *soudain vous ayez lâché votre corde*. (BUTOR, Modification, p. 223)
> **On répète seulement le *que* de la locution conjonctive**:
> ♦ *Jamais Noé ne put si bien voir le monde que de l'arche, malgré qu'elle fût close et* QU'*il fit nuit sur la terre*. (PROUST, Les plaisirs et
> les jours, p. 13)
> ♦ *Telle personne de cinquante ans, pourvu qu'elle fût coquette, bien mise*, QU'*elle eût une certaine peau, un certain regard [...], lui apparaissait [...] comme une «femme »*. (ROMAINS, 6 oct., p. 268)
> **Plus rarement quand la coordination est implicite (c'est-à-dire sans
> conjonction)** :
> ♦ *Lorsque la bise souffle sur les champs*, QUE *les bois perdent leurs dernières feuilles*. (CHAT., Génie, I, V, 7)
> ♦ *Cela se supporte [...] « la Sainte-Chapelle parce qu'elle est minuscule,* QU'*elle est un oratoire*. (HUYSMANS, Cathédrale, p. 406)
> **Il est rare aussi qu'une locution (ou quasi-locution) dont le dernier élément est où soit reprise par que** :
> ♦ *Au moment où il ouvrit la porte et* QUE *le pêne grinçait, il s'excusa du délabrement de cette « baraque »*. (REZVANI, Canard du doute, pp. 71-72)
> **Cela est facilité par le fait que au moment que coexiste avec *au moment où***.
> •
> **La conjonction n'est ni répétée ni reprise** :
> ♦ *Si je les soutiens toujours et je les soutiens trop*. (PÉGUY, Myst. des saints Innocents, p. 63)
> ♦ *En une longue plainte, comme celle du vent lui-même,* QUAND *il s'engage entre deux poutres ou il souffle au trou d'un mur*. (RAMUZ, Règne de l'esprit malin, II, 2)
> ♦ SI *vous aviez eu deux nez et je vous en aurais arraché un... combien vous en resterait-il maintenant ?* (IONESCO, Leçon, p. 70.)

---

> How ungrammatical, unidiomatic or heathen is it to write *si* where my red arrows below are pointing, rather than *que/qu'*?

There is no error of grammar in the choice being made, and at most a slight infringement on account of a not quite idiomatic turn, which, moreover, not everybody will notice or even reckon as real.

- S'il retéléphone demain et qu'il **veuille** savoir où j'étais, dis-lui que j'étais  chez ma mère.

The connection between "call again" and "wants to know" may exist or not. If the first call has been acknowledged as a call meant expressly to  inquire about the whereabouts of the person who is talking, then there is a connection, and it is perhaps preferable to use « que ».

- Si Hélène hérite de la maison et qu'elle la **vende**, tante Zoë sera furieuse.

If Hélène has been telling everybody that in case she inherited the house she would sell it, then there is a connection, and again  a majority of people will perhaps use « que », but the other possibility is acceptable.

- Si le temps change et qu'il **se mette** à pleuvoir, on annulera la sortie.

In this last case the two are more likely to be connected; the changing weather is really a hindrance if it is of the sort that results in rain; yet, not using « que » is acceptable.

There is below a personal example (user LPH) where, however, the use of « que » appears  more critical to me.

- Si pour toi le soleil tourne autour de la terre et **si** pour toi, de l'autre côté des océans il ne se trouve rien, et **que** les gens tombent tout simplement dans le vide lorsque ils arrivent là, eh bien alors tu es un homme du Moyen Âge.

There is no possible connection between the first two propositions, and it seems that  "que" would be somewhat  odd, but still possible; however, the last two propositions being connected in meaning the use of "que" seems better there; the use of "si" or "que" three times would not be stylistically as satisfying.